# 'posts' table should not store the absolute image path

Tags: posts, images, mysql, paths

I'm having some difficulty in making a sandbox from a website, and one of them is that wordpress is registering the absolute path of the image in `posts.guid` field:

`http://example.com/path/image.jpg`

I think the correct one would be just the relative path, ie

`/path/image.jpg`

So if I make a copy of the database and try to use it in another domain, or even sub-domain, the images will not appear.

How to solve this?

Comment: A search replace via WP CLI usually does the job. Also keep in mind that using relative URLs could lead to issues on multisite installs with mapped domains when using `switch_to_blog` or in RSS feeds when viewed elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little research I realized that it is an (inconvenient) feature of Wordpress to store the absolute path of the images and other files, something that I completely disagree with.

In any case, I discovered this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/root-relative-urls/.

It does not fix the urls of files already inserted, but it corrects those of the new files.

For a new installation, I understand then that this is an **essential plugin**.

In the meantime, I'll try to figure out how to fix all the fields of all tables that contain an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading this article https://yoast.com/dev-blog/relative-urls-issues/, I was demoted to accept that Wordpress really is right in leaving the absolute urls.

And I also noticed that the migration process is greatly facilitated by using this plugin: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
Thus, everything becomes easier and respecting current best practices.